# Interactive Python: cannot get `%lprun` to work, although line_profiler is imported properly

Tags: python, profiling, ipython, spyder, magic-function

## Problem

Most iPython "magic functions" work fine for me right off the bat:  `%hist`, `%time`, `%prun`, etc.  However, I noticed that `%lprun` could not be found with iPython as I'd installed it originally.

## Attempt to Resolve

I then discovered that I should install the `line_profiler` module.  I have installed this module, but still cannot seem to get the magic function to work correctly.  If I attempt to call `%lprun`, iPython still cannot find the function.  If I call it with the full name ( `line_profiler.magic_lprun` ), the function can be found, but I cannot get it to work at all.  Below is an example of what I'd done (which is taken step by step from "Python for Data Analysis" book):

### Success Using `%prun`

[In:]

```
def add_and_sum(x, y):
    added = x + y
    summed = added.sum(axis=1)
    return summed

x = randn(3000, 3000)
y = randn(3000, 3000)

add_and_sum(x, y)
```

With this I get a nice answer, as expected:

[Out:]

```
array([-23.6223074 , -10.08590736, -31.2957222 , ..., -14.17271747,
    63.84057725, -50.28469621])
```

And I can do the profiling magic function `%prun`:

[In:]

```
%prun add_and_sum(x, y)
```

[Out:]

```
6 function calls in 0.042 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.020    0.020    0.029    0.029 <ipython-input-27-19f64f63ba0a>:1(add_and_sum)
    1    0.013    0.013    0.042    0.042 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.009    0.009    0.009    0.009 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.009 _methods.py:16(_sum)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.009 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

### Fail Using `%lprun`

But when I try `%lprun`, I cannot get anything:

[In:]

```
%lprun -f add_and_sum add_and_sum(x, y)
```

[Out:]

```
ERROR: Line magic function `%lprun` not found.
```

And if I try to call the function with its standard name, it also does not work:

[In:]

```
line_profiler.magic_lprun -f add_and_sum.test test.add_and_sum(x, y)
```

[Out:]

```
line_profiler.magic_lprun -f add_and_sum.test test.add_and_sum(x, y)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But the library has been imported properly, or at least this is what it says:

[In:]

```
line_profiler
```

[Out:]

```
<module 'line_profiler' from '/Users/<edit>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/line_profiler-1.0b3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/line_profiler.pyc'>
```

[In:]

```
line_profiler.magic_lprun
```

[Out:]

```
<function line_profiler.magic_lprun>
```

It seems as if there is something extra that I am supposed to configure so that these new magic functions that I add can be identified as such.  I could not find anything via a web search.

I am running Spyder as an IDE (still using iPython as the console), but I have also tried it directly with iPython and with iPython notebook.  I have had no luck in any format.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have two ways to make work `%lprun`, one solution is temporal, i.e., it lasts until you finish your `ipython` session, and the other one is permanent.

**Temporal:** (as Carlos Cordoba's answer)

After starting `ipython` run the following:

```
In [1]: %load_ext line_profiler
```

**Permanent:**

Add the following lines to `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`:

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.extensions = [
    'line_profiler',
]
```

If you don't have the file `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`, you can create it by (see [this](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html) for more info):

```
ipython profile create
```

Answer (score 70):

To make `%lprun` work, you need to load the extension into your session, using this command:

```
In [1]: %load_ext line_profiler
```

Check out [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/3062428) to see some examples that use the magic.

Besides, if you are working with Spyder, there is also a third-party `line_profiler` plugin, which you can find [here](https://github.com/Nodd/spyder_line_profiler).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, Carlos!!  This worked for me... I could not seem to find this information anywhere on the web.

Comment: +1 for the `line_profiler` plugin if you're using Spyder. I find it's the least troublesome way to run `line_profiler` and the ouput it gives is nice.

Comment: sorry to say, but it doesn't work anymore (since IPython 5.)

Comment: @Alleo, not my fault :-) The `line_profiler` extension hasn't been updated to work with IPython 5.0. Please see https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/pull/65 for a fix

Comment: `%load_ext line_profiler` command works in IPython 5.0 with line_profiler version 2.0.