# Does pandas automatically skip rows do a size limit?

Tags: python, windows, pandas

We all know the question, when you are running in a memory error: [Maximum size of pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569771/maximum-size-of-pandas-dataframe/44207661)

I also try to read 4 large `csv-files` with the following command:

```
files = glob.glob("C:/.../rawdata/*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", encoding='unicode_escape') for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

The only massage I receive is:

> C:..\conda\conda\envs\DataLab\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3214:
>   DtypeWarning: Columns (22,25,56,60,71,74) have mixed types. Specify
>   dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.   if (yield from
>   self.run_code(code, result)):

which should be no problem.

My total dataframe has a size of: `(6639037, 84)`

Could there be any datasize restriction without an memory error? That means python is automatically skipping some lines without telling me? I had this with another porgramm in the past, I don't think python is so lazy, but you never know.

*Further reading:*
Later i am saving is as `sqlite-file`, but I also don't think this should be a problem:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/.../In.db')
df.to_sql(name='rawdata', con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: you can try saving the dataframe as a csv and compare the file size with respect to the input csvs. I think you can easily realize if something is missing. (The only difference should be the header only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an error in the file reading, so thanks @Oleg O for the help and tricks to reduce the memory.

For now I do not think that there is a effect that python automatically skips lines. It only happened with wrong coding. My example you can find here: [Pandas read csv skips some lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662420/pandas-read-csv-skips-some-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a generator expression to concat

```
dfs = (pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", encoding='unicode_escape') for f in files)
```

so you avoid the creation of that crazy list in the memory. This might alleviate the problem with the memory limit.

Besides, you can make a special generator that contains a downcast for some columns. 
Say, like this:

```
def downcaster(names): 
    for name in names:
        x = pd.read_csv(name, sep="\t", encoding='unicode_escape')
        x['some_column'] = x['some_column'].astype('category')
        x['other_column'] = pd.to_numeric(x['other_column'], downcast='integer')
        yield x

dc = downcaster(names)
df = pd.concat(dc, ...
```

Comment: I don't have a memory limit, or I don't even know that I have it

Comment: I believe, there's always a limit, i.e. sooner or later if you keep your DataFrame growing, you stumble upon a MemoryError. What I showed before are the tricks that I usually do to avoid it (I work with tables of up to 30 GB, so this is my everyday trouble).